# On every children add 1 (+1) Umbraco Razor

Tags: razor

In the code below i need it to add (+1) on every children on data-slide-index="0".

Starting at 0 and then 1,2,3,4,5

It should look like this:

```
data-slide-index="0"
data-slide-index="1"
data-slide-index="2"
```

I am thinking something like this.

```
int theCount = 0;
theCount += 1; // Adds 1 to count
```

But I dont know how to use it correctly in the code.

```
@foreach (var image in @Model.Children)
{
foreach (dynamic d in image.imageDampSingle)
{
<a data-slide-index="0" href="@DAMP_Helper.GetImageCropperUrl(d, "projectSingle")"><img src="@DAMP_Helper.GetImageCropperUrl(d, "projectSingleThumb")" title="@Model.captionText" alt="@d.Image.nodeName" /></a>
```

Or is there a easier / another way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

//René

Comment: No way to use recursion?

Comment: I am fairly new to razor so i have to admit that i don't know what recursion is.

Comment: Recursion is a principle in programming. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: Is there any chance that you can post an example on how you would do it?

Comment: I don't know Razor enough to do that. That's why I ask if Razor doesn't have the option of recursion.

Comment: That's okay I will try to find a solution and post it in here when it is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. See below:

```
                    @{
                var countNum = -1;
                }
                @foreach (var image in @Model.Children)
                {
                    {
                    countNum += 1;
                    }
                    foreach (dynamic d in image.imageDampSingle)
                    {
                        <a data-slide-index="@countNum" href="@DAMP_Helper.GetImageCropperUrl(d, "projectSingle")"><img src="@DAMP_Helper.GetImageCropperUrl(d, "projectSingleThumb")" title="@Model.captionText" alt="@d.Image.nodeName" /></a>
                    }
                }
```

You are welcome to comment on it regarding improvement of the code.

//René

Answer (score 0):

Razor is just a view engine, you are using C# code in there to do some logic operation. Recursive methods are algorithmic operations that have the capability to call themselves until a certain condition is satisfied. You can use a helper in this case to achieve that. An example for your case:

```
@helper DoSomething(IEnumerable<Something> myList)
{
    foreach (var item in myList)
    { 
         @item.CertainProperty 
         @if (item.Children.Any())
         {
             @DoSomething(item.Children)
         }
    }
}
```

Learn and read about recursion, and a whole new world of fundamental concepts will appear.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion

It's a fundamental topic, I was actually programming some snippets right now when I read this topic, where's other example in Python:

```
def contaVogais(cadeia):
    if not cadeia:
        return 0
    return (1 if cadeia[0] in 'aeiou' else 0) + contaVogais(cadeia[1:])
```

As you can see by the examples, recursive solutions are usually more elegant, **but in some cases** might have a decrease the code performance.

Comment: Great, recursion is a whole new continent and an important base.